# Nave XYZ senza articolo determinativo

Tags: word-usage, idioms

Facendo ricerche su mio nonno, ammiraglio di squadra al termine della carriera militare, ho scoperto che ci si riferisce spesso (almeno per iscritto) alle navi come Nave, con la N maiuscola, seguita dal nome, ma non preceduta dall'articolo determinativo. Ad esempio,

> mio nonno è stato comandante **di Nave Alpino** fino al 1941,

anche se colloquialmente, quando è chiaro il contesto, si dice semplicemente

> mio nonno è stato comandante **dell'Alpino** fino al 1941,

o, se è necessario specificare,

> mio nonno è stato comandante **del cacciatorpediniere Alpino** fino al 1941.

Sempre come esempio, [qui c'è un articolo su Nave Alghero](https://www.marina.difesa.it/noi-siamo-la-marina/mezzi/forze-navali/Pagine/Alghero.aspx) (la prima in ordine alfabetico sul sito della Marina Militare).

Non sono riuscito a trovare notizie su questo curioso uso di Nave XYZ senza articolo determinativo, e quindi mi chiedo e vi chiedo

- Come e quando è nato quest'uso?
- Quanto è frequente?
- Si ritrova anche nel parlato?
- Esistono usi simili anche in ambiti diversi dalla Marina Militare?

Comment: Sono un parlante nativo (benchè ignorante) e non avevo mai sentito questa forma.
+1.

Answer (score 5):

Mi sembra un uso insolito riferito a nomi di navi, secondo questa [fonte](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario-si-dice/I/il-mario-la-maria.shtml) (Corriere.it):

> - Il nome proprio può appartenere a una nave, e qui l’articolo è di solito femminile perché si concorda con il sottinteso “nave": la Santa Maria, la Michelangelo, la Garibaldi, la Bismark; ma il Rex (perché si sottintende “transatlantico”).

Leggendo il pezzo  su Nave Alghero, la mancanza dell'articolo sembra un uso proprio della Marina, del loro gergo. Sembra quasi che parlino della nave come una entità viva, di una persona. Infatti Nave Alghero o la Nave vengono scritte con le maiuscole (quasi fossero un nome e un cognome). Forse per questo loro non usano l'articolo mentre nel linguaggio comune si usa.

Comment: Non c'entra direttamente, ma mi ricorda il fatto che in inglese le navi sono uno dei pochissimi oggetti inanimati a cui ci si riferisce con *she* anziché con *it*.

Comment: Si..pensavo proprio a questo mentre scrivevo il commento..Il fatto mi sembra pertinente in quanto  indica in valore di una 'Nave' nell'ambiente della Marina in paesi come il nostro o quello inglese con forti tradizioni marinare.